# Modifying Word's Normal template company-wide

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-office, templates

We use Word 2003 on all computers; we also use Group Policy to set a shared "workgroup templates" folder, which is really useful as we can just copy .DOT files into there to make them accessible to all users.

We have a company policy that all documents must have a filepath and a page number in the footer. I'd love to be able to override the default Word template to include these if possible - can anyone suggest a neat, efficient way of doing it?

Thanking you in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your normal.dot and place it in the workgroup templates folder you've specified, and then ensure that there is no normal.dot in the user's template folder. This can be done using a logon script. Word will look for normal.dot in the following folders, and use the first one it finds:

- Program templates folder (there shouldn't be a normal.dot here, unless someone added it manually)
- User templates folder
- Workgroup templates folder

See also [KB826839](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826839).